# Successful RMAN restored database contains very old data

Tags: oracle, rman

I have an Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 database  that I am doing an RMAN test restore to a separate machine as part of DR preparedness test.  This same process has been done with no issues every few months for the last few years, but when trying today the restored data is not up to date.

The database restore/recovery appears to run through the current archivelogs with no issue and the database opens okay - however the restored data is over 12 months old.

**Controlfile restore**

I do this from autobackup - seems to restore todays as expected:

```
RMAN> restore controlfile from autobackup;

Starting restore at 09/07/2021 01:25:27
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=484 device type=DISK

recovery area destination: /u02/rman/r2db/recovery
database name (or database unique name) used for search: R2DB
channel ORA_DISK_1: AUTOBACKUP /u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/autobackup/2021_07_09/o1_mf_s_1077421497_jghkksgy_.bkp found in the recovery area
channel ORA_DISK_1: looking for AUTOBACKUP on day: 20210709
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring control file from AUTOBACKUP /u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/autobackup/2021_07_09/o1_mf_s_1077421497_jghkksgy_.bkp
channel ORA_DISK_1: control file restore from AUTOBACKUP complete
output file name=/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/r2db/control01.ctl
output file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/r2db/control02.ctl
Finished restore at 09/07/2021 01:25:28
```

The restore at this point runs as normal.

**Database Recovery (end of):**

This runs through up until the most recent archive file (from today). For future ref, this restore is being done on 9th July 2021, but the database timestamps are UTC time (about 12 hours out)

```
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_06/o1_mf_1_1_jg7ds1nx_.arc thread=1 sequence=1
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_06/o1_mf_1_2_jg7ds45d_.arc thread=1 sequence=2
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_06/o1_mf_1_3_jg7ds8j8_.arc thread=1 sequence=3
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_08/o1_mf_1_4_jgdxsrhk_.arc thread=1 sequence=4
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_08/o1_mf_1_5_jgdxss0d_.arc thread=1 sequence=5
archived log file name=/u02/rman/r2db/recovery/R2DB/archivelog/2021_07_08/o1_mf_1_6_jgdxssqh_.arc thread=1 sequence=6
archived log file name=/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/r2db/redo01.log thread=1 sequence=1
media recovery complete, elapsed time: 00:13:05
Finished recover at 09/07/2021 03:22:26


RMAN> alter database open noresetlogs;

Statement processed

RMAN> exit


Recovery Manager complete.
```

Everything seems fine... but looking at the data (using the heavily used login table) the most recent login is from over a year ago:

```
SQL> select max(updated_at) from login;

MAX(UPDATED_AT)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18-MAY-20 01.08.28.941494 PM
```

If I compare this to the production database this was restored from, the most recent login is (as expected) from earlier today:

```
MAX(UPDATED_AT)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
09-JUL-21 04.06.29.555764 PM
```

This data age is the same in all tables looked at - but login table gives a good idea as it's very heavily used.

Obviously I would be expecting a slightly older from producton result given the prod database has a few more hours of use on it, but would certainly expect a most recent login from earlier today, not 17 months ago.

I have read about database incarnations, but I don't really understand them - is it possible I'm restoring the data okay, but ending up in a different incarnation?

Comment: so this was an offline backup? (open noresetlogs succeeded) Dit you remove the old database before restoring? This has nothing to do with incarnations. Incarnations is about the internal housekeeping, not so much about user data. Do you happen to have a test 'login' table that you might be looking into?

Comment: it was an online backup (i thought).  Have just tried again making sure the database data files were all deleted  (previously they hadn't been), and getting the same results. Data files have all been recreated and have current system timestamps. There is a test schema on there - the date in that schema is (as expected) even older.